# How do I actually change variables and override styles in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I've stumbled upon this: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss

And in https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/generators/active_admin/assets/templates/active_admin.css.scss which is generated by ActiveAdmin to `app/assets/stylesheets`, I'm able to see change `$sidebar-width: 242px;` and it reacts, but if I try to add any of the other variables from https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss it simply ignores the changes to those variables. For instance, the following code does not make the bg color black...

```
// SASS variable overrides must be declared before loading up Active Admin's styles.
//
// To view the variables that Active Admin provides, take a look at
// `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss` in the
// Active Admin source.
//
// For example, to change the sidebar width:
$sidebar-width: 500px; // works
$body-background-color: #000; // doesn't work
```

I'm really not sure what to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/82402529125764229f5bb851d7b9073ad78eb536 added the ability to set variable overrides using SASS's `!default`, but there have been commits since then that didn't add `!default`, namely from https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/de62b3d7a68fc82f980a723f014ba844a635bea9

I just updated those variables on master: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/26d9b741ddb9176a8239f7508da508fccdbd8332